# File::Spec->catpath does not work for Windows

Tags: windows, perl, path

I am using the [`File::Spec` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) like this

```
my $volume = 'C';

my $path = File::Spec->catpath(
    $volume,
    File::Spec->catdir('panel', 'texts'),
    'file'
);

print $path;
```

### output

```
Cpanel\texts\file
```

How is `File::Spec` a portable module, as discussed in [How can I construct OS-independent file paths in Perl ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1818093) if I have to write the volume as `C:\` and not just `C` to get it right?

Comment: Couldn't `C` also refer to a machine on the network named `C`? e.g., `\\C\some\file`

Comment: Windows volume names are of the form `d:` or `\\sever\share` (which includes a lot of funky stuff like `\\.\C$`).

Comment: Tip: I find Path::Class much easier to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 problems.  The first is that Windows volume names include the colon, so you should have said `$volume = 'C:'`. The second is that you specified a relative path, so you got a relative path.  If you want an absolute path, you have to give one:

```
use 5.010;
use File::Spec;

my $volume = 'C:';
my $path = File::Spec->catpath($volume,
    File::Spec->catdir('', 'panel', 'texts'), 'file');
say $path;
```

On Windows, that will print `C:\panel\texts\file`, and on Unix it will say `/panel/texts/file`.

Note that it's perfectly legitimate to have a relative path with a volume name on Windows:

```
File::Spec->catpath('C:',
    File::Spec->catdir('panel', 'texts'), 'file');
```

will give you `C:panel/texts/file`, which means `panel/texts/file` relative to the current directory on drive `C:`.  (In Windows, each drive has its own current directory.)